# Search within a BuildRowSetFromXML or XML for value

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Edit: to clarify, IF "abcd" is contained in XML, then output X. 
OR, IF "abcd" is contained in BuildRowSetFromXML, then output X.

I need ampscript that will search for a value within a BuildRowSetFromXML table or just from the entire referenced XML in general.

Lets say the BuildRowSet loops through and adds 3 values to the table--I need to be able to search for value "abcd" within that table, and return "true" if in fact TRUE.

I tried the following with the thinking that I would declare a variable true/false if the value was present, and then on every loop if it was "true", keep the variable as is. This is not working though as it ultimately returns false.

```
%%[ Set @itemID = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,'//product-lineitems/product-lineitem/product-id',1) ]%%

%%[ 

For @i = 1 To RowCount(@itemNameRows) Do 

 Set @itemIDs1 = Row(@itemID, @i)

]%% 
    %%[ 

    Var @roseRose
    Var @roseRoseCheck

    if v(Field(@itemIDs1,"Xml"))=="abcd" then 
        set @roseRoseCheck = "true" 
    else 
        set @roseRoseCheck = "false" 
    endif

    if @roseRose=="true" then

    else

        if @roseRoseCheck=="true" then 
            set @roseRose = "true" 
        else 
            set @roseRose = "false" 
        endif

    endif

%%[ Next @i ]%%


%%[ if @roseRose=="true" then ]%%
true
%%[ else if @roseRose=="false" then ]%%
false
%%[ endif ]%%
%%[ else ]%%
wrong
%%[ endif ]%%
```

An example of the XML i'm trying to parse out below.

```
<product-lineitems>
    <product-lineitem>
      <net-price>79.95</net-price>
      <tax>0.00</tax>
      <gross-price>79.95</gross-price>
      <base-price>79.95</base-price>
      <lineitem-text>itemA</lineitem-text>
      <tax-basis>0.00</tax-basis>
      <position>1</position>
      <product-id>abcd</product-id>
      <product-name>itemA</product-name>
      <gift>false</gift>
    </product-lineitem>
    <product-lineitem>
      <net-price>69.95</net-price>
      <tax>0.00</tax>
      <gross-price>69.95</gross-price>
      <base-price>69.95</base-price>
      <lineitem-text>itemB</lineitem-text>
      <tax-basis>0.00</tax-basis>
      <position>2</position>
      <product-id>efgh</product-id>
      <product-name>itemB</product-name>
      <gift>false</gift>
    </product-lineitem>
  </product-lineitems>
```

Comment: You've got a dangling else/endif at the end.  Is this all the code?

Comment: Also, can you update your question and include the XML you're trying to parse?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs updated to include XML. I think the else/endif is fine here though.

Comment: Can you also include your buildrowsetfromXML code?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search using XPath. Something like this:

```
%%[

var @xml
set @xml = ""
set @xml = concat(@xml,"<product-lineitems>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"  <product-lineitem>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <net-price>79.95</net-price>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <tax>0.00</tax>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <gross-price>79.95</gross-price>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <base-price>79.95</base-price>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <lineitem-text>itemA</lineitem-text>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <tax-basis>0.00</tax-basis>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <position>1</position>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <product-id>abcd</product-id>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <product-name>itemA</product-name>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <gift>false</gift>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"  </product-lineitem>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"  <product-lineitem>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <net-price>69.95</net-price>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <tax>0.00</tax>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <gross-price>69.95</gross-price>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <base-price>69.95</base-price>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <lineitem-text>itemB</lineitem-text>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <tax-basis>0.00</tax-basis>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <position>2</position>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <product-id>efgh</product-id>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <product-name>itemB</product-name>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"    <gift>false</gift>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"  </product-lineitem>")
set @xml = concat(@xml,"</product-lineitems>")

var @searchRowSet
var @searchXPath
set @searchProduct = "abcd"
set @searchXPath = concat('//product-lineitem[product-id="', @searchProduct, '"]')

set @searchRowSet = buildrowsetfromXML(@xml, @searchXPath)

if rowcount(@searchRowSet) > 0 then
  output(concat("<br>found"))
else 
  output(concat("<br>not found"))
endif

]%%
```

**Output**

```
found
```

I've found [**XPather.com**](https://www.xpather.com) to be helpful in figuring out how to target specific elements.  I just pasted your XML into the site and built the path until it returned what I wanted.  Then I just translated it back to the [**BuildRowsetFromXML**](https://ampscript.guide/buildrowsetfromxml) syntax.

Comment: this was it. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

I personally use IndexOf AMPScript function to check for keywords within a defined variable or string.

This function returns character position where string occurs in the variable. Index numbering begins with 1.

```
 %%[
    SET @string = 'ab'

    SET @Find = IndexOf(@string,'a')
    ]%%

%%=v(@Find)=%%
```

The result of above will be **1**

Reference: [IndexOf](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/IndexOf.htm)

Comment: I've tried this but you cant use IndexOf on a table, it has to be text. is there a way to just convert the row table to text?